# How to multiply all the values in an array together in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Say I have some array

`int[] arr = {3,7,10,2};`

And I want to create a loop to multiply each value to get the product (in this case 420) what would that loop look like?

EDIT: a BigInteger will be required for the program I am trying to write

Comment: The first thing to think about is how big the result is likely to be.  Will an `int` be big enough (up to about 2 billion)?  Or a `long` (up to about 19 digits)?  Or do you need `BigInteger`?  The answer to that affects the code you're going to write.

Comment: OK, without giving you the whole answer (since this looks rather like homework), one key step is going to be multiplying your product so far by a new entry from the array.  This is going to require converting the array entry to a `BigInteger` prior to the multiplication.  It might look something like `product = product.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(entry));`.  You can find information about other methods of the `BigInteger` class on [its Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem thank you but just because its simple doesn't mean its hw lol

Answer (score 0):

`Stream#reduce` can do the math repetitively.

Make example input data.

```
List< BigInteger > inputs =
    List.of( 
        new BigInteger( "3" ) , 
        new BigInteger( "7" ) , 
        new BigInteger( "10" ) , 
        new BigInteger( "2" ) 
    ) ;
```

Make a stream of that list of inputs. Apply the `multiply` method.

```
Optional< BigInteger > result = 
    inputs 
    .stream()
    .reduce( BigInteger :: multiply )
;
```

See this [code run live](https://ideone.com/UfVXHc) at IdeOne.com.

> Optional[420]

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class Multiply {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        int[] arr = {3,7,10,2};
        BigInteger mul = BigInteger.valueOf(1); // neutral element as start value
        for (int i : arr) { // iterate over array 
            mul = mul.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }
        System.out.println(mul);
    }
}
```

produces

```
$ java Multiply.java
420
```